# Changing a variable through a button click; Python 3.4

Tags: python, button, click

Alright, so I have some code that I am using for a little clicker game I'm making for myself. I am trying to have the button with the original cost printed on it, and then, when I click the button, the cost updates on the button and the cost actually increases to the user. Take a look.

These are all of my variables.

```
click = 0
mult = 1
dcp1 = 0
autoclickers = 0
mines = 0
grandmas = 0
doubleclickcost = 5
autoclickercost = 7
minecost = 10
grandmacost = 15
costmultiplyer = 1.3
```

Btw I am just taking out the code in question. This is the code that handles the grandma cost.

```
purchaseGrandmaButton = Button(master, text="Purchase Grandma - " + str(grandmacost) + " Clicks", command = purchaseGrandmaCommand)
purchaseGrandmaButton.pack()
```

So what I am trying to do is have the button update the amount that the button displays the cost of the grandmas.http://puu.sh/hOWdf/0970e92276.png <- Before I buy a grandma. http://puu.sh/hOWfy/6dad5b94bb.png <- After I buy a grandma. The number/cost on the button doesn't change, and I want it to, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reconfigure the button's text each time it's clicked:

```
grandmacost = 15

def purchaseGrandmaCommand():
    global grandmacost
    grandmacost +=15
    global purchaseGrandmaButton
    purchaseGrandmaButton.config(text="Purchase Grandma - " + str(grandmacost) + " Clicks"
```